# Default values in bootstrap-select with Laravel without js

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, bootstrap-select

I would like to display default values inside of my select using bootstrap-select, when I'm editing it. How can I achieve this?

bootstrap-select sends data in array, but could I pass aray into it? How could I set default value of select?

**Data that goes as default**

```
@foreach ($product->categories as $origin)
    {{$origin->category->id}} // <- This one needs to be sent
    {{$origin->category->name}} // <- This one needs to be displayed
@endforeach
```

**My select:**

```
<select name="category_id[]" values="" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
   @foreach($categories as $category)
      <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

**I tried doing it using an array, so I would just put array into values:**

```
@foreach ($product->categories as $index=>$origin)
    {{$passTo[$index] = $origin->category->id}}
    {{$origin->category->name}}
@endforeach
```

**But there are two problems:**

1. It prints the value while creating array (since {{}} is like echo in blade)
2. It doesnt work:

```
<select name="category_id[]" values="{{$passTo}}" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
```

[image]

**My second idea** was to pass them as selected options but I dont know how to avoid duplicating records between 2 foreaches:

```
@foreach($product->categories as $origin)
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        @if ($category->id == $origin->category->id)
            <option value="{{$origin->category->id}}" selected>
                {{$origin->category->name}}
            </option>
        @else
            <option value="{{$category->id}}">
                {{ $category->name }}
            </option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Second solution might be the easiest one, but still I`m not sure how to complete it :c

Screen of what I would like to achieve(just in case)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best solution. But it works :)

```
                @php
                    $taken = array();
                    foreach ( $product->categories as $origin )
                    {
                        array_push($taken, $origin->category);
                    }
                    $all = array();
                    foreach ($categories as $category)
                    {
                        array_push($all, $category);
                    }
                    $rest = array();
                    $rest = array_diff($all, $taken);
                @endphp
```